Runtime Error when creating PySpark session on Juypter Notebook on Wins
When I tried running the command below on the Juypter:
 spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()

It gives this error:
 RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

I did the checking on the anaconda prompt
**Manage to resolve it by restarting the ananconda. The error is resolved though it states warning her and there.
Input:
 java --version

Output:
java 21.0.4 2024-07-16 

Input:
javac --version

Output:
javac 21.0.4

Input:
echo $JAVA_HOME

Output:
$JAVA_HOME
 

What possibility that I haven't done. I have also created the environment variable and added the java path to it. Thanks

AFAIK Spark can't run on Java 21?
